# pandas: add row in dataframe if value is NaT

Tags: python, pandas

I have the dataframe below

```
guest                  dat1           dat2                   f1               f2
guest1  2021-10-21 16:01:01  2021-10-21 08:19:17            NaT             NaT
guest2  2021-10-21 10:41:53  2021-10-24 07:53:57  2021-10-21 08:19:17  2021-10-21 10:41:53
guest3  2021-10-21 09:00:00  2021-10-21 10:00:00            NaT                  NaT
guest4  2021-10-21 10:00:00  2021-10-22 14:00:00  2021-10-21 10:00:00  2021-10-21 10:00:00
```

I want to apply function where value of f1 and f2 are NaT, So if f1 and f2 are NaT, then add row are shown in my expected output where per guest f1 of

- the first row takes 2021-10-21 00:00:00 and f2 takes dat1
- the second row takes dat2 and f2 takes 2021-10-21 23:59:59.

**My expected output**

```
  guest                 dat1                  dat2                f1                 f2

  guest1  2021-10-21 16:01:01  2021-10-21 08:19:17       2021-10-21 00:00:00    2021-10-21 16:01:01
  guest1  2021-10-21 16:01:01  2021-10-21 08:19:17       2021-10-21 08:19:17     2021-10-21 23:59:59
  guest2  2021-10-21 10:41:53  2021-10-24 07:53:57       2021-10-21 08:19:17    2021-10-21 10:41:53
  guest3  2021-10-21 09:00:00  2021-10-21 10:00:00       2021-10-21 00:00:00    2021-10-21 09:00:00
  guest3  2021-10-21 09:00:00  2021-10-21 10:00:00       2021-10-21 10:00:00    2021-10-21 23:59:59          
  guest4  2021-10-21 10:00:00  2021-10-22 14:00:00       2021-10-21 10:00:00    2021-10-21 10:00:00
```

**code**

```
reps = [2 if val=="NaT" else 1 for val in df.f1]
df = df.loc[np.repeat(df.index.values, reps)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Extract the subset where `f1` and `f2` have `NaT`. For `row_1` make changes in original dataframe, for `row_2` use the subset and
concat it to the original dataframe.:

```
cond = (df['f1']=='NaT') & (df['f2']=='NaT')
df_subset = df[cond].replace('NaT', np.nan)
df_subset['f1'] = df_subset['f1'].fillna(df_subset['dat2'])
df_subset['f2'] = df_subset['f2'].fillna(datetime(2021, 10, 21, 23, 59, 59))

df['f1'] = df['f1'].replace('NaT', np.nan).fillna(datetime(2021,10,21))
df['f2'] = df['f2'].replace('NaT', np.nan).fillna(df['dat1'])

df = pd.concat([df, df_subset], ignore_index=True)
df.sort_values(by=['guest']).reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

`OUTPUT:`

```
    guest                 dat1                 dat2                   f1                   f2
0  guest1  2021-10-21 16:01:01  2021-10-21 08:19:17  2021-10-21 00:00:00  2021-10-21 16:01:01
1  guest1  2021-10-21 16:01:01  2021-10-21 08:19:17  2021-10-21 08:19:17  2021-10-21 23:59:59
2  guest2  2021-10-21 10:41:53  2021-10-24 07:53:57  2021-10-21 08:19:17  2021-10-21 10:41:53
3  guest3  2021-10-21 09:00:00  2021-10-21 10:00:00  2021-10-21 00:00:00  2021-10-21 09:00:00
4  guest3  2021-10-21 09:00:00  2021-10-21 10:00:00  2021-10-21 10:00:00  2021-10-21 23:59:59
5  guest4  2021-10-21 10:00:00  2021-10-22 14:00:00  2021-10-21 10:00:00  2021-10-21 10:00:00
```

Comment: You have to import this `from datetime import datetime`

Comment: I resolved with adding .fillna(datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 21, 23, 59, 59)), another problem with thid row **df_subset['f1'] = df_subset['f1'].fillna(df_subset['dat2'])**: it fills the f1 with linux time how to deal with it please?.

Comment: I didn't get you. because this line `df_subset['f1'] = df_subset['f1'].fillna(df_subset['dat2'])` is supposed to fill `nulls` in `f1` column with whatever exist in the respective row in `dat2` column. So may be you should check your `dat2` column/

Comment: for example my dat2 contains 2021-10-21 21:35:52 and my f1 was filled with 1634852152000000000 . This int is called unix date . Hope im clear now https://www.epochconverter.com/

Comment: Can you try this: `df_subset['f1'].fillna(df_subset['dat2'].astype(str))`

Comment: it is empty now

Comment: This is strange. did you set it back i.e. `df_subset['f1'] = df_subset['f1'].fillna(df_subset['dat2'].astype(str))`

Comment: it works fine now thank you !! ^^

Comment: Please consider, accepting the answer, if helped. :)